# how can i get links on page that have a certain word in them with javascript

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am trying to get the link that contains a word on a page and refresh them to another page, in a bookmarklet.

Here is the code I am not getting to work for a bookmarklet:

```
   javascript:
        for (i=0; i < document.links.length; i++) {
     if(document.links[i].href.match('exampleword')) {
    location.href = 'http://google.com/exampleword'; 
}
}
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 2):

Greg was sharp to catch that you really want the link "*label*", rather than the href URL. But I would grab all of the elements with ***getElementsByTagName('A')***. Then iterate through their ***firstChild*** nodes.

It's just as easy to pick up the '***nodeValue***' of the '***firstChild***', as it is to get the innerHTML or (innerText, which someone mentioned, which is less supported).

Here's a minimal example, looking for 'word1', 'word2', and 'word3'.

I will just add, that if you want to limit the links looked at for this to a subset of the links on the page or site, you could differentiate in other ways, by setting a particular className to the links you want to search. It would just complicate matters a bit to check the className of the links you grab. Herewith, a simple A Node iteration:

EXAMPLE:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript match link label</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var keywords = ['word1','word2','word3'];
function linklabels() {
    var aels = document.getElementsByTagName && document.getElementsByTagName('A');
    var aelsCt = aels.length;
    var keywordsCt = keywords.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < aels.length; i++) {
        var v= aels[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
            //this is the link label, the text seen as the link
        for (var j=0; j < keywordsCt; j++) {
            var re = new RegExp(keywords[j]); 
            if (re.test(v)) {
                alert('refreshing to http://google.com/' + v);
                //window.location.href = "http://google.com/" + v;
            }
        }
    }
}
window.onload=linklabels;
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p><a href="#">word1</a> | <a href="#">word2</a> | <a href="#">word3</a>
<br /><a href="#">word1</a> | <a href="#">word2</a> | <a href="#">word3</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using firstChild is okay, as long as all of your links are marked-up consistently. In some situations, for example when you have nested inline tags (<strong>, <span>, etc.), it might be better to capture all textual content using innerText || textContent.

Comment: @J-P, excellent point. Going with the node methodology, I would alter the above to dig down through any children of each A tag element for text nodes (nodeType 3) before grabbing the nodeValue. (Fortunately, I built and use a function that does all of that for me in the background.) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're checking if the link href contains the word - from your question it sounds more like you want the anchor text (i.e. the words you click on). The easiest way (though not 100% accurate if the `<a>` contains other tags) is like this:

```
if (document.links[i].innerHTML.match('exampleword'))
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to search for innerText || textContent?

Comment: Oh I see. How can I display the link then: location.href = document.links[i].href?

Comment: sorry I'm a newb at javascript